# Cyprus to Gaza by sea in an inflatable craft

Tags: international-travel, sea-travel, extreme-tourism, mediterranean, palestine

Because of the political situation in my home land °Palestine Gaza°, now 2 million people are trapped in 360 km square called °Gaza strip° and they are left without sea port, airport, or land port.
Living here in Marseilles in the south of France makes this idea unacceptable for me, that I can't go to visit my family.
So I am thinking to travel by sea using an inflatable  boat with 15 hp outboard  motor from Cyprus to the beach of my city and symbolically break this siege. It is almost 400 km.

I have a lot of questions.

I used to fishing in Gaza, but I never go more far than 3 km in the sea which is allowed depth you can go before get shoot by the israeli marine.

1. Is it possible to do 400 km with an inflatable boat and a 15 hp motor?
2. How much fuel do I need considering there is just one passenger?
3. What speed can I go and how much time do I need to make this distance?
4. What kind of GPS guides I can use to do this trip?

[image]

Comment: Hi Alghoul, and welcome to Travel.  On this website, we normally ask one question per post, so I would recommend to split your question into four different questions.  Also, please don't get yourself killed by either the sea or the Israeli marine.

Comment: This is an incredibliy interesting, and I think partially on-topic question, however it is currently too broad, as you are asking a number of questions in a single post. Also, a couple of the questions aren't really on-topic here (how much fuel you need, for instance. This depends on the efficiency of your motor, wind speed, ocean currents, and possibly other factors, which we cannot know)

Comment: Your last question should be answerable here, about GPS. The others, I'm not so sure... When you ask about speed, do you mean legally, or are you talking about the speed possible with your motor and craft (obviously we have no way of knowing that).

Comment: Is Cyprus really the closest point you could get to to begin this journey?  Why not pick a point on the coast that is closer to Gaza?

Comment: As a warning, I think you will have to put out from Cyprus surreptitiously. Although relations between the Cypriot government and Israel are not warm, there is definitely cooperation on "security" matters. Indeed, you might be less likely to be stopped shortly after leaving port if you depart from Turkish-occupied Northern Cyprus, although that political situation is also volatile. And it makes for an even longer journey.

Answer (score 3):

First, I’m sorry to hear about the problems in Palestine area. I hope things work out soon.

This is a very interesting question. Here is my attempt to answer it.

[Europe seeks to open Gaza sea route from Cyprus.](http://www.worldbulletin.net/gaza-tunnels/142331/europe-seeks-to-open-gaza-sea-route-from-cyprus)

Your questions:

> 1. Is it possible to do 400 km with an inflatable boat and a 15 hp motor?

I think it is possible but it seems very risky and not sure about the **safety** in open waters there. 400 km seems like a very long travel in an inflatable boat with 15 hp motor.

> 2. How much fuel do I need considering there is just one passenger?

Like Flimzy commented it definitely depends on the efficiency of your motor, wind speed, ocean currents, and possibly other factors.

> 3. What speed can I go and how much time do I need to make this distance?

Boat with that power could do 35-40 km/h or approx. 25 mph or slight more with flat calm waters, light weight, no wind.

> 4. What kind of GPS guides I can use to do this trip?

There are many kinds of handheld GPS devise are available but depending on the short space that an inflatable boat has “The Garmin GPSMAP 62s” might be a good idea. “Garmin GPSMap 400” series is very good too with a large screen but not suitable for an inflatable boats I reckon. [(Source)](http://www.my-inflatable-boat.com/gps-reviews.html)

Some general [tips](http://www.grandboats.com/adv-boating.htm) and [faqs](http://www.boatstogo.com/faq.asp)  for using an inflatable boat.

Also take a look at this question it is quite related but the boat they are talking about is much smaller. [Still a good read.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37951/how-far-can-you-realistically-travel-across-potentially-rough-water-in-an-inflat)